# Android NDK profiler for native executable produces no data

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, profiling

I am using the Android NDK to build a native C/C++ binary via `include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)`. I have added the android-ndk-profiler module to my Android.mk according to their instructions and added calls for `monstartup` and `moncleanup`.

Running the binary on a rooted device produces gmon.out, and everything appears to be working correctly. But running $ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/.../arm-linux-androideabi-gprof shows the headers and descriptions, but no actual data.

I know the profiler intended to be used for native shared libraries and not executables, but is it possible to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to profile executables by tricking the profiler into thinking your executable is actually a shared library. The profiler requires you to pass in your library name to `monstartup` so that it can look up memory mapping information. If you pass it "your_lib.so", it will look for mappings with the name "libyour_lib.so".

So in your startup code, put:

```
monstartup("myexecutable.so");
```

Push the binary to your device and rename it to **lib**myexecutable.so. Then run it and enjoy your profiling data.

Note: this was tested using NDK r10d and android-ndk-profiler 3.3.